# How can I prevent FL from echoing the notes I play in a MIDI keybord back to the keyboard?

Tags: fl-studio

The only way I know to do this is to turn the MIDI channel volume down, but then this makes impossible to play back to my keyboard something I recorded before while I'm recording something else with the same keyboard.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Please, mine is yamaha dx21 and i have the same problem. How do i turn the local of the keyboard off?

Answer (score 3):

Select the FL mixer track your recording to, turn off the send switch at the bottom of the master track.

Comment: I think tracks don't apply to MIDI do they? How do I know which mixer track I'm recording to?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any notes to be sent to the keyboard, make sure they're sent on a different MIDI channel than the keyboard is responding to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to play the sound on your keyboard but not double strike note, you need to turn the Local command to Off. Tell me the brand of your keyboard and I will tell you how to shut it off (if it can be done).

Comment: Yamaha P-85. In Cubase you'd do this by turning off MIDI Thru.